# convert a data string to float in Java

Tags: java, types, combobox

I have the problem that in my program I have 4 annotated combo boxes and 2 of them return a number but in String type, which I need to store in a floating type variable, My combo box is called combo2 and
jComboBox4, the 2 variables that you see are the ones in which I need to store the data but I need to convert them. I would appreciate your help. Greetings.

//My combobox is combo2 and jComboBox4
// I need save in this variables

```
private void jButton1MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
     int numeroextra1;
     int numeroextra2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert string variable to float as following:

```
string s = "123.45";
float f = Float.parseFloat(s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following methods:

```
String s = "10.01";
Float fObject = Float.valueOf(s);//get Float object
float fNumber = Float.parseFloat(s);//get float number
```

Comment: It's correct but i need use the value that return combo2

Comment: It would be helpful if you could share more of the code